# Sometimes goroutine NOT get event data from channel

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

My issue is sometimes goroutine NOT get event data from reg.eventCh

NO exit log print, this goroutine is NOT exit, is running.

`reg.eventCh` channel is NOT closed, log can print length increment.

Logs shows :

```
reg.eventCh <- event, count: 1
event is coming

reg.eventCh <- event, count: 0  (why count is 0? log print after data in channel)
event is coming

reg.eventCh <- event, count: 1

reg.eventCh <- event, count: 2
.
.
.
reg.eventCh <- event, count: 999

reg.eventCh <- event, count: 1000
```

log shows DO NOT get event data from reg.eventCh,
belows is my codes：

```
reg := &Reg{}
reg.exitCh = make(chan *demo.Exit)
reg.eventCh = make(chan *demo.Event, 1000)

go reader(reg)

// other goroutine will writer event to reg.eventCh like:

reg.eventCh <- event
log.Println("reg.eventCh <- event, count:",len(reg.eventCh))


func reader(reg *Reg) {
    for {
        select {
            case event := <-reg.eventCh:
                log.Println("event is coming")
                handler(event)
            case exit := reg.exitCh:
                log.Println("exit")
                return
        }
    }
}
```

Is my codes something wrong?

any help will be appreciated,

Thanks,

Jimmy

demo code：

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

type Event struct {
    testStr string
}

type Exit struct {
    testStr string
}

type Reg struct {
    des     string
    eventCh chan *Event
    exitCh  chan *Exit
}

// this demo code like my issue
// this issue is sometimes case event := <-reg.eventCh NOT work in go reader()
func main() {
    reg := &Reg{}
    reg.des = "sometime not read from reg.eventCh"
    reg.eventCh = make(chan *Event, 1000)
    reg.exitCh = make(chan *Exit)

    // read data from channel
    go reader(reg)

    // simulate data: write in channel
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go writer(reg)
    }

    select {}
}

func writer(reg *Reg) {
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(500)) * time.Millisecond)
        event := new(Event)
        event.testStr = "1"
        reg.eventCh <- event
        log.Println("reg.eventCh <- event, channel count:", len(reg.eventCh))
    }
}

func reader(reg *Reg) {
    for {
        select {
        case event := <-reg.eventCh:
            log.Println("event is coming, channel count:", len(reg.eventCh))
            handler(event)
        case exit := <-reg.exitCh:
            log.Println("goroutine exit: ", exit)
            return
        }
    }
}

func handler(e *Event) {
    // logic codes
}
```

need time to repro this issue。

Comment: provide a complete example we can execute via `go run test.go` to reproduce the behavior described in your post.

Comment: @mh-cbon this is a logic code from my micro-service. NOT always run bad like this, i will prepare a demo codes and run.

Comment: there must be something else you have not grasped because the shared code has no reason to not read all data written to eventCh and end up in deadlock.

Comment: @mh-cbon yes,the whole codes are more, this is only a demo codes from my micro service. maybe handle data hanging？ maybe any other reason...

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some errors! It dont send data to exitCh, it dont has stop condition and deadlock block. I will share my answer by answering 3 questions I raised.

**Question#1**:
`why count is 0? log print after data in channel`

***len(channel)** is only useful to know how much data is currently available. If the recipient has already received the data, it will always be 0.*

**Question#2**: why use select like exit control?

*you could use `<-context.Done()` or others code more idiomatic.*

**Question#3**: why there is no data for exitCh?

*apparently you created an exitch to get out of the loop, but it’s not working*

Code sugestion:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var (
    ctx, cancel = context.WithCancel(context.Background())
)

type Event struct {
    testStr string
}

type Exit struct {
    testStr string
}

type Reg struct {
    des     string
    eventCh chan *Event
    exitCh  chan *Exit
}

// this demo code like my issue
// this issue is sometimes case event := <-reg.eventCh NOT work in go reader()
func main() {
    //
    reg := &Reg{}
    reg.des = "sometime not read from reg.eventCh"
    reg.eventCh = make(chan *Event, 1000)
    reg.exitCh = make(chan *Exit)

    // read data from channel
    go reader(reg)

    // simulate data: write in channel
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go writer(reg, fmt.Sprintf("gorouinte-%d", i))
    }
    // notify exit
    <-ctx.Done()
}

func writer(reg *Reg, tname string) {
    for /* infinity loop */ {
        // time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(100)) * time.Millisecond)
        event := new(Event)
        event.testStr = "1"
        reg.eventCh <- event
        log.Println("reg.eventCh <- event, channel count:", len(reg.eventCh))
        // simulates stop condition
        if len(reg.eventCh) == 1000 {
            reg.exitCh <- &Exit{"exit now!"}
            log.Printf("stop write loop in routine %s\n", tname)
            return
        }
    }
}

func reader(reg *Reg) {
    for {
        select {
        case event := <-reg.eventCh:
            log.Println("event is comming, channel count:", len(reg.eventCh))
            handler(event)
        case exit := <-reg.exitCh:
            log.Println("goroutine exit: ", exit)
            cancel() // used to exit this program
            return
        }
    }
}

func handler(e *Event) {
    // logic codes
}
```

[Playground demo](https://play.golang.org/p/KbP-1g3aKoJ)

Comment: thank you for the reply. Demo codes not include whole codes in my micro-service.
Pls ignore exit channel, my issue has no data in exit channel.
I want to know if my code logic is wrong, i.e. go reader() to handler data.